# Single instance of reusable HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, web-services, wcf

I've got this method and I realize that an instance of `HttpClass` is going to be created for each call to it. While working seemingly OK, I'm considering moving it out and placing it as a private property accessible to each call to the method. There might be other methods making use of it in the future as well. I have no information on how often these calls will occur. (There's a `try`/`catch` too but it's omitted for brevity's sake.)

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Poof"]
public async Task<String> GetPoof()
{
  String url = BaseUrl + "poofy";
  using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
      "Authorization", GetAuthorizationSchema());
    HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(url);
    return await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }
}
```

What I'm thinking of is something like this:

```
private HttpClient _Client
private HttpClient Client { get { return _Client ?? GetNewClient(); } }

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Poof"]
public async Task<String> GetPoof()
{
  String url = BaseUrl + "poofy";
  HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(url);
  return await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

My worry is, though, that the different calls utilizing the same client instance will somehow collide and call huge issues later on, especially if the number of calls per time unit raises beyond a critical level. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't need multiple instances. In fact, `HttpClient` is designed specifically to persist and be used for multiple requests (see: `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`).

There's already a lot written about this so I'll redirect you to those resources:

- [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)
- [Is HttpClient safe to use concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178220/is-httpclient-safe-to-use-concurrently)
- [What is the overhead of creating a new HttpClient per call in a WebAPI client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client)

Comment: Another link worth reading: [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
private HttpClient Client { get { return _Client  = _Client ?? GetNewClient(); } }
```

Instead of

> ```
> private HttpClient Client { get { return _Client ?? GetNewClient(); } }
> ```

Comment: This spells out how to exploit [HttpClient safe to use concurrently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69954/93149) - as opposed to *trying*.

Comment: Actually, I prefer to use an static HttpClient variable and the initialization inside the static constructor of the main class