# Throwing exception in the singleton pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I'm implementing an HTTP client shell that's going to be used for the lifetime of my application in C#.  It needs to be initialized before the instance can be accessed.  It looks something like this:

```
public static class AssetSyncServiceClient {
    private static object _lock = new object();
    private static bool _initialized = false;
    private static HttpClient _client = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the client has been initialized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Whether the client is initialized.</returns>
    public static bool IsInitialized() {
        lock (_lock) {
            return _initialized;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and configures HTTP client.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Initialize(string baseUrl, bool onlyRequestJson = true) {
        lock (_lock) {
            if (_initialized) { throw new Exception("Client has already been initialized."); }

            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

            if (onlyRequestJson) {
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            }

            _initialized = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes / disposes of the HTTP client.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Close() {
        lock (_lock) {
            if (_initialized && _client != null) {
                _client.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets client instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static HttpClient Instance {
        get {
            lock (_lock) {
                if (!_initialized) { throw new Exception("HTTP client has not been initialized."); }
                return _client;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is, this throws up a warning in Visual Studio because of style rule CA1065 - Microsoft say you shouldn't throw an exception in a property.  I just don't agree with this - it seems fine to me.  If you try to access `.Instance` before it's initialized you get an exception.  It's clearly a property whose code could throw an exception, and not a "dumb field".  I could turn `Instance` into a `GetInstance` method but I just prefer the look of accessing it from calling code as a property.

So does it make sense to just suppress the warning here, or am I designing this badly?  Is there a better way?  Should I bite the bullet and make `Instance` a method?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like I probably want something other than a singleton because singletons are hard to test (although actually MS Fakes can mock static methods so maybe it's OK), so what would be a better design pattern for this functionality that's unit testable?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient

Answer (score 2):

- The initialize dance is not nice. Requires the caller to keep track of if it has been called etc. Pit of failure.
- The IsInitialized() is not very useful as it is now as there no way to lock over check and initialize. There will always be a risk that another thread calls Initialize between the check IsInitialized and the call to Initialize.
- I have not used `HttpClient` much but my gut feeling is that the locking is not needed.
- A singleton will make it hard to mock in tests. What about writing it like this:

```
public class AssetSyncServiceClientSettings
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public bool JsonOnly { get; set; }
}

public interface IAssetSyncServiceClient : IDisposable
{
    // Picked a sample method randomly, you can expose an api that makes sense in your app/lib
    Task<string> GetStringAsync(string requestUri);
}

public sealed class AssetSyncServiceClient : IAssetSyncServiceClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private bool _disposed;

    public AssetSyncServiceClient(AssetSyncServiceClientSettings settings)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);

        if (settings.JsonOnly)
        {
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }

    public Task<string> GetStringAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        VerifyNotDisposed();
        return _client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;
        _client.Dispose();
    }

    private void VerifyNotDisposed()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

- Doing it like this avoids initialization. If you need it lazy for some reason the service could handle it internally.
- An interface probably makes sense for this so you can mock it in tests.
- Use the Dependency Injection container to make the service a singleton instance.
- Pass in the service interface in to constructors where it is needed. It makes the dependency explicit and makes it easy to mock in tests.
- The settings object can perhaps contain urls so that the service can expose methods like `public async Task<Stuff> GetStuffAsync()`

Comment: Good answer.  One point I don't quite understand is "Pass in the service interface in to constructors where it is needed." - is that just a general principle, or are you referring to somewhere you have done this in your example code?

Comment: It is a general principle, constructor injection, not shown in the sample code. Or in a way it is, we pass in `AssetSyncServiceClientSettings` in the constructor of the client. Pass in `IAssetSyncServiceClient ` the same way where the service is used.

Comment: One way I'm thinking of making this a singleton (without the complexity of a full Dependency Injection framework) is by using a "singleton factory"; a factory that creates/gets only one instance of an `IAssetSyncServiceClient`. Does that sound like a decent compromise?

Comment: Could be but you want it written in a way so that it can return a mock in tests I think. IoC frameworks are not hard, I can walk you through it later when I get home. Imo no app is too small for IoC. Ping me in chat in a couple of hours.

Comment: Which chatroom?

Comment: By the way, although I implemented the factory as a static method and a static member, with MS Fakes and shims you can even mock statics so I think that factory should be mockable for unit testing.

Comment: I never had much luck with fakes. I think I'd hack it with reflection in tests. Many ways to solve it.