# Custom HttpClient Wrapper

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I need to wrap httpClient because I'm using a custom token provider. I will use this code with asp.net mvc to communicate with our webApi2 server. ( Using webApi2 with directly from ui with angularjs etc. off the case. )

I shared this code and asking your opinions because;

- I don't want any deadlock to occur.
- I see code reuse which is bad (but don't know how to solve).
- Maybe throwing exceptions somehow different and correct way.
- It supposed to work under huge load (150K realtime requests from
  users)

*Note: I implemented it with concerns of di. So I can wrap restSharp too.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyLibrary.Core.Components.Json;
using MyLibrary.Core.Components.Json.Implementations;

namespace MyLibrary.HttpClientWrapper
{
    public class ResourceServerRestClient : IResourceServerRestClient
    {
        private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;
        private readonly IJsonManager _jsonManager;

        public ResourceServerRestClient(ITokenProvider tokenProvider, IJsonManager jsonManager)
        {
            _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
            _jsonManager = jsonManager;
        }

        public string BaseAddress { get; set; }

        public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, string clientId)
        {
            return CheckAndInvokeAsync(async token =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {         
                    ConfigurateHttpClient(client, token, clientId);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                    }

                    var exception = new Exception($"Resource server returned an error. StatusCode : {response.StatusCode}");

                    exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);

                    throw exception;
                }
            });
        }

        public Task<T> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(object data, string uri, string clientId)
        {
            return CheckAndInvokeAsync(async token =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    ConfigurateHttpClient(client, token, clientId);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                    }

                    var exception = new Exception($"Resource server returned an error. StatusCode : {response.StatusCode}");

                    exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);

                    throw exception;
                }
            });
        }

        public async Task PostAsJsonAsync(object data, string uri, string clientId)
        {
            await CheckAndInvokeAsync(async token =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    ConfigurateHttpClient(client, token, clientId);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var exception = new Exception($"Resource server returned an error. StatusCode : {response.StatusCode}");

                        exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);

                        throw exception;
                    }
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
        }

        public Task PutAsJsonAsync(object data, string uri, string clientId)
        {
            return CheckAndInvokeAsync(async token =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    ConfigurateHttpClient(client, token, clientId);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, data);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var exception = new Exception($"Resource server returned an error. StatusCode : {response.StatusCode}");

                        exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);

                        throw exception;
                    }
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
        }

        public Task<T> PutAsJsonAsync<T>(object data, string uri, string clientId)
        {
            return CheckAndInvokeAsync(async token =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    ConfigurateHttpClient(client, token, clientId);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, data);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                    }

                    var exception = new Exception($"Resource server returned an error. StatusCode : {response.StatusCode}");

                    exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);

                    throw exception;
                }
            });
        }

        private void ConfigurateHttpClient(HttpClient client, string bearerToken, string resourceServiceClientName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceServiceClientName))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CN", resourceServiceClientName);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BaseAddress))
            {
                throw new Exception("BaseAddress is required!");
            }

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
        }

        private async Task<T> CheckAndInvokeAsync<T>(Func<string, Task<T>> method)
        {
            try
            {
                string token = await _tokenProvider.IsTokenNullOrExpired();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    return await method(token);
                }

                var exception = new Exception();
                exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                throw exception;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Data.Contains("StatusCode") && ((HttpStatusCode)ex.Data["StatusCode"]) == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    string token = await _tokenProvider.GetTokenAsync();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        return await method(token);
                    }
                }

                throw;
            }
        }

        public void ThrowResourceServerException(List<string> messages)
        {
            string message = messages.Aggregate((p, q) => q + " - " + p);

            var exception = new Exception(message);

            exception.Data.Add("ServiceOperationException", message);

            throw exception;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use IHttpClientFactory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one way to do it

```
public class ResourceServerRestClient : IResourceServerRestClient
{
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;
    private readonly IJsonManager _jsonManager;
    private HttpClient _client;

    // you can inject the interfaces
    public ResourceServerRestClient(ITokenProvider tokenProvider, IJsonManager jsonManager)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        _jsonManager = jsonManager;
    }

    // who set this property?
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }

    // this is just to demonstrate a simple reuse technique. you can do it in other ways. (singleton, DI, static)
    public HttpClient Client => _client ?? (_client = new HttpClient());

    public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, string clientId)
    {
        return InvokeAsync<T>(
           clientId,
           client => client.GetAsync(uri),
           response => response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>());
    }

    public Task<T> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(object data, string uri, string clientId)
    {
        return InvokeAsync<T>(
           clientId,
           client => client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data),
           response => response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>());
    }

    public Task PostAsJsonAsync(object data, string uri, string clientId)
    {
        return InvokeAsync<object>(
            clientId,
            client => client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data));
    }

    public Task PutAsJsonAsync(object data, string uri, string clientId)
    {
        return InvokeAsync<object>(
            clientId,
            client => client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, data));
    }

    public Task<T> PutAsJsonAsync<T>(object data, string uri, string clientId)
    {
        return InvokeAsync<T>(
            clientId,
            client => client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, data),
            response => response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>());
    }

    private async Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(
        string clientId,
        Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> operation,
        Func<HttpResponseMessage, Task<T>> actionOnResponse = null)
    {
        if(operation == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(operation));
        // consider to make pre check validation also to clientId argument if it's needed

        var token = GetToken();

        ConfigurateHttpClient(_client, token, clientId);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await operation(_client).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var exception = new Exception($"Resource server returned an error. StatusCode : {response.StatusCode}");
            exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);
            throw exception;
        }
        if(actionOnResponse != null)
        {
            return await actionOnResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    private string GetToken()
    {
        // if IsTokenNullOrExpired return null and not string.Empty, you can do the foloowing:
        var token = await _tokenProvider.IsTokenNullOrExpired() ?? await _tokenProvider.GetTokenAsync();
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            var exception = new Exception();
            exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            throw exception;
        }
        //else, do this:
        string token = await _tokenProvider.IsTokenNullOrExpired();
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            token = await _tokenProvider.GetTokenAsync();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var exception = new Exception();
                exception.Data.Add("StatusCode", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        return token;
    }

    private void ConfigurateHttpClient(HttpClient client, string bearerToken, string resourceServiceClientName)
    {
        // do this first
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(BaseAddress))
        {
            throw new Exception("BaseAddress is required!");
        }
        // consider to do pre check also for arguments if it make sense

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceServiceClientName))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CN", resourceServiceClientName);
        }

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
    }
}
```

I hope it's help..

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dudi Keleti, I'm reviewing/thinking your code rightnow. But I have one quick question. Can you explain to me in just a few sentences, why all async calls (get,put,post,delete etc.) should use ".ConfigureAwait(false);". I mean, i think, there is no gui or "main thread" in one mvc request to webapi. Why I need to use it?

Comment: because you don't care about capturing the current context. if it was UI work then it will be ConfigureAwait(true). check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more info

Comment: Is it good to re-create httpClient for every request? I found these: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient

Comment: @Lost_In_Library yep the link is correct. reuse the client if there is no reason to recreate. if you want I can update my answer later today.

Comment: please update sir. I can do it myself but it's for community. If someone will find this Q&A again, he/she should the last version of it :) I <3 Community

Comment: @Lost_In_Library done:) if it's seems OK for you, please accept the answer.