# Custom Binance API wrapper around IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I made a custom Binance API wrapper (`BinanceRestClient`) which uses `IHttpClientFactory` in order to prevent socket exhaustion, while also ensuring that DNS changes are respected.

I looked at the implementation of a deprecated API wrapper ([this one](https://github.com/glitch100/BinanceDotNet/blob/master/BinanceExchange.API/Client/BinanceClient.cs#L354)) and I realized how clean they did it. For ex. my `GetBalances()` method is around 20 lines of code, compared to theirs (1 line of code). [This one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124155/custom-httpclient-wrapper) could be added as a reference too.

I then tried to do the same by creating the `BinanceApiProcessor` class. It works. However, I think my implementation of `InvokeAsync<T>` is not clean. This is how we call the class:

```cs
public Task<AccountTradeResponse?> GetMyTrades(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    using var apiProcessor = new BinanceApiProcessor(_httpClientFactory);

    const string symbol = "DOGEUSDT";

    return apiProcessor.InvokeAsync<AccountTradeResponse>(HttpMethod.Get, EndpointSecurityType.UserData,
        "/api/v3/myTrades", $"symbol={symbol}&recvWindow=5000", ct);
}
```

I would like to get code review, because I know things could be made in a cleaner way.

### API Processor class

```cs
internal class BinanceApiProcessor : IDisposable
{
    private const string BaseAddress = "https://api.binance.com";
    private const string ApiKey = "xxx";
    private const string SecretKey = "xxx";

    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Whether this instance is disposed.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BinanceApiProcessor" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpClientFactory"></param>
    public BinanceApiProcessor(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The HTTP client.
    /// </summary>
    private HttpClient HttpClient
    {
        get
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(BaseAddress, nameof(BaseAddress), "BaseAddress is required");

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("UTF-8"));

            return client;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Timestamp in milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The current timestamp in milliseconds.</returns>
    private static long GetNonce()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates HMAC signature for signed endpoints.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="secretKey">The secret key.</param>
    /// <param name="payload">URL encoded values that would usually be the query string for the request.</param>
    /// <returns>A ct representing the request params.</returns>
    private static string CreateSignature(string secretKey, string payload)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(secretKey, nameof(secretKey));
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(payload, nameof(payload));

        using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
        var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        return BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    public async Task<T?> InvokeAsync<T>(
        HttpMethod httpMethod,
        EndpointSecurityType securityType,
        string endpoint,
        string? parameters = default,
        CancellationToken ct = default)
        where T : class
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(endpoint, nameof(endpoint));

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        //============================================
        // TODO: Implement a rate limiter
        var queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();

        foreach (var (key, value) in QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(parameters))
            queryBuilder.Add(key, value.ToString());

        if (securityType is EndpointSecurityType.Trade or EndpointSecurityType.UserData)
        {
            queryBuilder.Add("timestamp", GetNonce().ToString());

            var queryString = queryBuilder.ToQueryString().ToString()[1..]; // ignore first character '?'. Binance requires it like so: "symbol=DOGEUSDT&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1637590595930"
            var signature = CreateSignature(SecretKey, queryString);
            queryBuilder.Add("signature", signature);
        }

        var uri = $"{endpoint}{queryBuilder.ToQueryString()}";

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);

        if (securityType != EndpointSecurityType.None)
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);

        using var httpContent = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        if (httpMethod == HttpMethod.Post || httpMethod == HttpMethod.Put || httpMethod == HttpMethod.Delete)
            httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;

        //============================================

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return json.FromJson<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The standard dispose destructor.
    /// </summary>
    ~BinanceApiProcessor()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Throw if disposed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    private void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException($"{nameof(BinanceApiProcessor)} has been disposed");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">If this method is called by a user's code.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

### REST Client class

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Binance REST implementation.
/// </summary>
internal class BinanceRestClient : IDisposable
{
    private const string BaseAddress = "https://api.binance.com";
    private const string ApiKey = "xxx";
    private const string SecretKey = "xxx";

    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Whether this instance is disposed.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BinanceRestClient" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpClientFactory"></param>
    public BinanceRestClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The HTTP client.
    /// </summary>
    private HttpClient HttpClient
    {
        get
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(BaseAddress, nameof(BaseAddress), "BaseAddress is required");

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("UTF-8"));

            return client;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Timestamp in milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The current timestamp in milliseconds.</returns>
    private static long GetNonce()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates HMAC signature for signed endpoints.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="secretKey">The secret key.</param>
    /// <param name="payload">URL encoded values that would usually be the query string for the request.</param>
    /// <returns>A ct representing the request params.</returns>
    private static string CreateSignature(string secretKey, string payload)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(secretKey, nameof(secretKey));
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(payload, nameof(payload));

        using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
        var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        return BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Test the connectivity to the API.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<EmptyResponse?> TestConnectivityAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        const string endpoint = "/api/v3/ping";

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint);

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Deserialize
        return json.FromJson<EmptyResponse>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the current server time (UTC).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<ServerTimeResponse?> GetServerTimeAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        const string endpoint = "/api/v3/time";

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint);

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return json.FromJson<ServerTimeResponse>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets current user balances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<AccountInformationResponse?> GetBalancesAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        var queryString = $"timestamp={GetNonce()}";
        var endpoint = $"/api/v3/account?{queryString}&signature={CreateSignature(SecretKey, queryString)}";

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint);
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return json.FromJson<AccountInformationResponse>();
    }

    public Task<AccountTradeResponse?> GetMyTrades(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        using var apiProcessor = new BinanceApiProcessor(_httpClientFactory);

        const string symbol = "DOGEUSDT";

        return apiProcessor.InvokeAsync<AccountTradeResponse>(HttpMethod.Get, EndpointSecurityType.UserData,
            "/api/v3/myTrades", $"symbol={symbol}&recvWindow=5000", ct);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a listen key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<UserDataStreamResponse?> CreateListenKeyAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        const string endpoint = "/api/v3/userDataStream";

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return json.FromJson<UserDataStreamResponse>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Keeps alive a listen key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listenKey">The listen key.</param>
    /// <param name="ct"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<EmptyResponse?> KeepAliveListenKeyAsync(string? listenKey,
        CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(listenKey, nameof(listenKey));

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        var endpoint = $"/api/v3/userDataStream?listenKey={listenKey}";

        using var httpContent = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, endpoint);
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);
        httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return json.FromJson<EmptyResponse>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Deletes a listen key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<EmptyResponse?> DeleteListenKeyAsync(string? listenKey, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        var endpoint = $"/api/v3/userDataStream?listenKey={listenKey}";

        using var httpContent = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, endpoint);
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);
        httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Ensures OK status
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Get response string
        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return json.FromJson<EmptyResponse>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The standard dispose destructor.
    /// </summary>
    ~BinanceRestClient()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Throw if disposed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException"></exception>
    private void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException($"{nameof(BinanceRestClient)} has been disposed");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">If this method is called by a user's code.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `BinanceApiProcessor` implemented as disposable? I don't see any cleanup. Same applies for `BinanceRestClient`.

Comment: @PeterCsala, because it's incomplete. I'm about to implement the rest of the endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinanceApiProcessor` and `BinanceRestClient` are the same, and they've got me confused as I thought they were separate classes, but then I got that feeling that one of them might act as base class of the other. Then, after reading both multiple times, I saw that `BinanceApiProcessor` is meant to serve as a `Client`, while the `BinanceRestClient` used as a `Service`.

(I'm not good in explaination, but I'll do my best).

To give a clear idea for why `BinanceApiProcessor` should be `Client` and `BinanceRestClient` should be `Service`, given the current project,
If we say `BinanceRestClient` then generally, it's assumed this class is already configured to call Binance API service, and it will handle the communication between endpoints to provide an easier API to interact with the external API, adding some room to the consumer for customizations. (Such as configuring authentications and authorizations, headers, calling different endpoints with different versions ..etc.) So, `BinanceApiProcessor` fits this role. However, `BinanceRestClient` is a `Service` as `Service` would consume the `Client`s internally with fixed rules, and the scope would be narrowed for a single purpose, which would add more restriction to the consumer, by using preconfigured settings and endpoints with limited usage, and closed-arguments  (e.g. `GetServerTimeAsync`, `GetBalancesAsync`).

A few other small notes on the current classes before we go further :

- `HttpClient` settings should be configured at `Startup`.
- `BaseAddress`, `ApiKey`, and `SecretKey` should be stored in the `appsettings.json`
- if the API provider have multiple API versions, try to implement each one of them separately, and then use a service class to consume them as needed.
- `GetNonce` would be better if it's an extension with a more clearer name like `GetUtcNowTimestamp`.
- `CreateSignature` would be better if it's an extension with a more clearer name like `CreateHMACSHA256Hash`.
- `InvokeAsync` this is too general, `ProcessRequest` or `SendRequest` or `GetRequestResult` ..et. would be more clearer.
- when you need to create `QueryString` use `QueryBuilder` or `QueryString` or `KeyValuePair` or `Dictionary` to have more manageable, and readable query string, and avoiding human-mistakes.
- use a better naming conventions, and avoid unreadable names such as `ct` which would be better if you just do `cancellationToken`.
- Always use `DRY` principle, along with other good coding principles. This would make your coding-life easier, and your work will always be as pretty as a child face ;).
- I'm not against using `IDisposable` on new implementations, however, when the class is ready to be shipped, ensure that there is an actual using of the interface, if there is no objects to dispose, then remove the `IDisposable` implementation before shipping the class for the next stage. *(`.NET Core` ensure to avoid disposing objects that were created by the service collection as it's handled by the DI container)* [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912160/should-httpclient-instances-created-by-httpclientfactory-be-disposed).(thanks to @PeterCsala).

**My Proposal** (not the best, but it will drive you there):

What I think would work better in your case is to rename `BinanceApiProcessor` to `BinanceApiClient` and `BinanceRestClient` to `BinanceApiService`.

### **BinanceApiClient**

The purpose of this class is to have a pre-configured instance of `HttpClient` to fit the provider rules, and add an easy interface for the consumer to interact with.

Example : (shorten for brevity)

```
internal class BinanceApiClient
{
    private readonly string _apiKey;
    private readonly string _secretKey;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    
    private HttpClient HttpClient => _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    
    // this should be moved into an extension or helper class
    private long UtcNowTimestamp => DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp();

    public BinanceApiClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, string apiKey, string secretKey)  { ... }

    // holds the Request arguments
    internal class RequestArguments { ... }

    // for building and processing the request arguments
    internal class RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> where T : class
    {
        // to generate the Api url along with queryStrings if applicable.
        private string GetEndPointUrl(string endpoint, bool useSecuritySignature = false, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null) { ... }
        
        // the underlying request processer 
        private async Task<T> ProcessRequest<T>(RequestArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class { ... }
        
        // exposed processor would be called whenever the consumer is done building the request.
        public async Task<T> Process() { ... }
    }

    
    // this should be moved into an extension or helper class
    private string CreateSignature(string payload) { ... }

    //to return the builder instance for the general usage
    internal RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> PrepareRequest<T>() where T : class { ... }
    
    //an overload of PrepareRequest<T> that would be configured as replacement of `InvokeAsync`
    internal RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> PrepareRequest<T>(HttpMethod httpMethod, EndpointSecurityType securityType, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class { ... }

    
}
```

### **BinanceApiService**

The purpose of this class is to use `BinanceApiClient` internally, and configure the api endpoints for an easier access for the consumer.

Example : (shorten for brevity)

```
public class BinanceApiService
{
    private readonly string ApiKey = /* Get the value from the appsettings.json */;
    private readonly string SecretKey = /* Get the value from the appsettings.json */;
    private const string symbol = "DOGEUSDT";

    private BinanceApiClient _client;

    public BinanceApiService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = new BinanceApiClient(httpClientFactory, ApiKey, SecretKey);
    }

    /*
        BaseAddress has been configured at Startup with https://api.binance.com/v3/
        if multiple versions are used, then a class for each version is recommanded.
        then, recall them in this class.
    */
    
    // basic processor with no content, no parameters, no security signature, no api-key
    public async Task<EmptyResponse?> TestConnectivityAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await _client
            .PrepareRequest<EmptyResponse>()
            .Method(HttpMethod.Get)
            .Endpoint("ping")
            .WithCancellationToken(cancellationToken)
            .Process();
    }

    // basic processor with no content, and no parameters but with security signature, and api-key
    public async Task<AccountInformationResponse?> GetBalancesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await _client
            .PrepareRequest<AccountInformationResponse>()
            .Method(HttpMethod.Get)
            .Endpoint("account")
            .UseApiKey()
            .UseSecuritySignature()
            .WithCancellationToken(cancellationToken)
            .Process();
    }

    // basic processor with empty content, parameters and api-key, but no security signature
    public async Task<EmptyResponse?> KeepAliveListenKeyAsync(string? listenKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {

        return await _client
            .PrepareRequest<EmptyResponse>()
            .Method(HttpMethod.Put)
            .Endpoint("userDataStream")
            .WithEmptyStringContent()
            .WithParameters(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("listenKey", listenKey)
            })          
            .UseApiKey()
            .WithCancellationToken(cancellationToken)
            .Process();
    }
    
    // this calls the `InvokeAsync` replacement.
    public async Task<AccountTradeResponse?> GetMyTrades(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await _client
            .PrepareRequest<AccountTradeResponse>(HttpMethod.Get, EndpointSecurityType.UserData, cancellationToken)
            .Endpoint("myTrades")
            .WithParameters(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("symbol", symbol),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recvWindow", "5000")
            })
            .Process();
    }

}
```

these are just examples, hope that will give you a better view.

Here is the full implementation of `BinanceApiClient`

```
internal class BinanceApiClient
{
    private readonly string _apiKey;
    private readonly string _secretKey;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    
    private HttpClient HttpClient => _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    private long UtcNowTimestamp => DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp();

    public BinanceApiClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, string apiKey, string secretKey)
    {
        _apiKey = apiKey;
        _secretKey = secretKey;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    internal class RequestArguments
    {
        public HttpMethod Method { get; set; }
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Parameters { get; set; }
        public HttpContent Content { get; set; }
        public bool UseApiKey { get; set; }
        public bool UseSecuritySignature { get; set; }
        public CancellationToken CancellationTokenValue { get; set; }
    }

    internal class RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly RequestArguments _args;
        private readonly BinanceApiClient _client;
        internal RequestArgumentsBuilder(BinanceApiClient client)
        {
            _args = new RequestArguments();
            _client = client;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> Method(HttpMethod httpMethod)
        {
            _args.Method = httpMethod;
            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> Endpoint(string endpoint)
        {
            Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(endpoint, nameof(endpoint));
            _args.Endpoint = endpoint;
            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> WithParameters(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
        {
            if(parameters != null)
                _args.Parameters = parameters;

            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> WithContent(HttpContent content)
        {
            if(content != null)
                _args.Content = content;

            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> WithEmptyStringContent(bool useWhenTrue = true)
        {
            if(useWhenTrue)
                _args.Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            
            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> UseApiKey(bool useApiKey = true)
        {
            _args.UseApiKey = useApiKey;                
            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> UseSecuritySignature(bool useSecuritySignature = true)
        {
            _args.UseSecuritySignature = useSecuritySignature;
            return this;
        }

        public RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> WithCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _args.CancellationTokenValue = cancellationToken;

            return this;
        }

        public async Task<T> Process()
        {
            return await _client.ProcessRequest<T>(_args, _args.CancellationTokenValue = default);
        }
    }

    private string CreateSignature(string payload)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(_secretKey, nameof(_secretKey));
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(payload, nameof(payload));

        using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretKey));
        var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        return BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    private string GetEndPointUrl(string endpoint, bool useSecuritySignature = false, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        string queryString = string.Empty;

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvps = parameters?.ToList() ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder;

        bool hasQueryString = false;

        if (kvps.Count > 0)
        {
            queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(kvps);
            hasQueryString = true;
        }
        else
        {
            queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
        }

        if (useSecuritySignature)
        {
            queryBuilder.Add("timestamp", UtcNowTimestamp.ToString());

            var uncodedQueryString = queryBuilder.ToQueryString().ToString()[1..];

            var signature = CreateSignature(uncodedQueryString);

            queryBuilder.Add("signature", signature);

            hasQueryString = true;
        }

        if (hasQueryString)
            queryString = queryBuilder.ToQueryString().ToUriComponent();


        return $"{endpoint}{queryString}";
    }

    private async Task<T> ProcessRequest<T>(RequestArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        where T : class
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(arguments.Endpoint, nameof(arguments.Endpoint));

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        ThrowIfDisposed();

        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(arguments.Method, GetEndPointUrl(arguments.Endpoint, arguments.UseSecuritySignature, arguments.Parameters));

        if(arguments.UseApiKey)
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", _apiKey);

        if (arguments.Content != null)
            httpRequestMessage.Content = arguments.Content;

        using var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, cancellationToken);

        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);

        return json.FromJson<T>();
    }

    internal RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> PrepareRequest<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new RequestArgumentsBuilder<T>(this);
    }

    internal RequestArgumentsBuilder<T> PrepareRequest<T>(HttpMethod httpMethod, EndpointSecurityType securityType, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class
    {
        return
            PrepareRequest<T>()
            .WithEmptyStringContent(httpMethod == HttpMethod.Post || httpMethod == HttpMethod.Put || httpMethod == HttpMethod.Delete)
            .UseApiKey(securityType != EndpointSecurityType.None)
            .UseSecuritySignature(securityType is EndpointSecurityType.Trade or EndpointSecurityType.UserData)
            .WithCancellationToken(cancellationToken);
    }


}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131796/discussion-on-answer-by-isr5-custom-binance-api-wrapper-around-ihttpclientfactor).